# Selenium find element by text with &#65279?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm pretty new to test automation so how I can click some a link if I know only partial text. 
I know that there is `find_element_by_partial_link_text` but there are words in the code that appear randomly `&#65279;`. I am not able to click by partial text if it appears `&#65279;`, for instance:

I know only word Example
`<a class="name-link">First Exa&#65279;mple</a>`
I am unable click by class because there are a lot of the same class. 
So is there any way to ignore `&#65279;`?

I am writing in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match link by word `"Example"` you can try to use search by XPath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(., "Exa") and contains(., "mple")]').click()
```

But note that it also will match, for example, link `"Examine the sample"`

If this not an option for you, you might need to use more complex xpath:

```
//a[starts-with(substring-after(., " "), "Exa") and substring(substring-after(., " "), 5) = "mple"]
```

to match string in format *"(string)(space)Exa(extra non-ascii character)mple"*

Also note that method `find_by_link_text()`/`find_by_partial_link_text()` searches for text **as it appears on page**, but not **as it appears in HTML source code**, so you can just copy text from page rendered by browser and use it as argument for `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text()`

Answer (score 2):

Try to `click()` the element through :

- `Partial Link Text`

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("First Exa").click()
  ```
- `XPath`

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='name-link' and contains(.,'First Exa')]").click()
  ```

Comment: Since OP mentioned "Example" was the only word they have to go on, I much prefer your XPath approach, as it guarantees we're only finding name-link classes as opposed to any link that happens to contain the word "Example".